# NotifyPropertyChanged, view only updates when event bound to command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, icommand

I am still fairly new to c# and WPF so perhaps this is expected but I find it strange and I can't seem to get around it.

I have a window with an area to input information about an event and a submit button along with some `datagrids` bound to `observable collections`. The button is bound to a command on my viewmodel and when a new event is entered I make some changes to the `observable collections` and the `datagrids` on the view are updated.

The issue is when a cell on one of the `datagrids` is edited. I have tried binding the `celleditended` event to a command on my view model [without much success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668735/custom-datagrid-event-not-firing) so I am trying it a different way by using the code behind event handler. I pass the edit information I need to the viewmodel make the changes to the observable collections in exactly the same way as it works above and can see the change in the `observable collection` but the view doesn't update. The `notifypropertychange` doesn't fire and neither does the `notifycollectionchange`.

So why does the `observablecollection` seem to only fire a property or collection change to update the view when the event is through a Command?

Full Code follows:

XAML code for the main window view; and the example [here](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/xceedwpfdatagrid/Custom_Cell_Editors.html) is where I got the xcdg:CellEditorBinding bit from.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTextblock">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:D}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="HistoryViewSource" Source="{Binding History, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Date" Direction="Descending"/>
        </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>

    <ViewModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowCollections"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Account Balances and Spending goals-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <!--History-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Account Balances-->
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="AccountsWidth" Width="Auto"/>
            <!--Categorized spending goals-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="AccountsDataGrid"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              AutoCreateColumns="False"
                              SelectionMode="Single" 
                              FontSize="14" 
                              Height="Auto"
                              Width="Auto">

            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                <xcdg:Column Title="Account" FieldName="Name">
                    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                        <xcdg:CellEditor>
                            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="AccountText" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Style="{StaticResource MainTextboxStyle}" MinWidth="100"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                        </xcdg:CellEditor>
                    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                </xcdg:Column>

                <xcdg:Column Title="Balance" FieldName="Balance">
                    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                        <xcdg:CellEditor>
                            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding Balance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Style="{StaticResource DecimalUpDownStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                        </xcdg:CellEditor>
                    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                </xcdg:Column>
                </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </Grid>

    <xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" x:Name="HistoryDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HistoryViewSource}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoCreateColumns="False"  SelectionMode="Single" FontSize="14" xcdg:Cell.EditEnded="HistoryDataGrid_EditEnded"> 
        <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding TransactionEditCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->

        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xcdg:Column Title="ID" FieldName="ID" Visible="False"/>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Type" FieldName="Type"/>

            <xcdg:Column Title="Amount" FieldName="Amount">
                <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:C}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>

                <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
                    <xcdg:CellEditor>
                        <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Style="{StaticResource DecimalUpDownStyle}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                    </xcdg:CellEditor>
                </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
            </xcdg:Column>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
</Grid>
```

The View Code behind file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowViewModel mainwindowviewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }

    public void HistoryDataGrid_EditEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainwindowviewmodel.HistoryCellEdit(e);
    }
}
```

The View Model code

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Accounts = DatabaseFunctions.getAccountData();
        History = DatabaseFunctions.getHistoryData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<AccountsModel> accounts;
    public ObservableCollection<AccountsModel> Accounts
    {
        get { return accounts; }
        set
        {
            accounts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Accounts");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<HistoryModel> history;
    public ObservableCollection<HistoryModel> History
    {
        get { return history; }
        set
        {
            history = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("History");
            History.CollectionChanged += History_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public ICommand HistoryEditCommand
    {
        get { return new ParamDelegateCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(HistoryCellEdit); }
    }

    public void HistoryCellEdit(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAccountData("Chequing", 200);
    }

    public void UpdateAccountData(string AccountName, decimal NewBalance)
    {
        var item = Accounts.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == AccountName);
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Balance = NewBalance;
        }
    }

    void Accounts_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (AccountsModel item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += Accounts_PropertyChanged;
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (AccountsModel item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= Accounts_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void History_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (HistoryModel item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += History_PropertyChanged;
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (HistoryModel item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= History_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Accounts_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void History_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The Accounts Model

```
public class AccountsModel : ObservableObject
{
    private Double id;
    public Double ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
        }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Name");
        }
    }

    private decimal balance;
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        set
        {
            balance = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Balance");
        }
    }
}
```

This History Model

```
public class HistoryModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    private Double id;
    public Double ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ID");
        }
    }

    private string type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set
        {
            type = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Type");
        }
    }

    private decimal amount;
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return amount; }
        set
        {
            amount = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Amount");
        }
    }
}
```

Notify Property Changed

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Add the code to model, viewmodel, and relevant xaml. This suggests your MODEL doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The `ObseravbleCollection` doesn't notify the view if PROPERTIES of elements changed unless elements also implement the interface.

Comment: Seems like there's information missing. Is Categories the ObservableCollection? If so, are the items in themselves observable?

Comment: @zaitsman I have added a piece of the CategoriesModel. Short story, every element of every model has the RaisePropertyChangedEvent. The UpdateCategoryData is in the view model. It gets called any time I need to change a value in the Categories observable collection. As for the xaml code I don't even know what part would be relevant but I have added the data grid bit. Thank you for help.

Comment: @glenebob Categories is the Observable Collection and the model does (as far as I understand it) implement notifyproperty changed; I have added a portion of the Categories model. Thank you for your help

Comment: So what binding do you use from the datagrid columns to the object properties?

Comment: @slugster As I am using the WPF extended toolkit I set the ItemsSource to the observable collection and then each column is set as <xcdg:Column Title="Category" FieldName="Category"> obviously the field name changes based on the property. Should there be more then that for the binding?

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a _minimal_ code example that still reproduces the issue. Post that example as a _complete_ code example that can be compiled and run without any additional work by your readers. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details on how to accomplish this and why it's important to do so.

Comment: Not seeing what is wrong, as it looks like the items in Categories do fire the correct change notification. But this line `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Categories");` looks entirely unneeded to me.

Comment: @glenebob Thank you for taking a look any way. I agree that line is not needed. I started adding it everywhere trying to get the view to update.

Comment: You can't just use the FieldName if you want changes to make it back and forth between the column and underlying data object, you need to specify a binding.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to diagnose the issue

Comment: @slugster I have tried some various bindings for the columns but it still doesn't update. I had followed the suggestion here: http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/19645.aspx

Comment: @AnthonyRussell can you suggest what more code I would need to add? As far as I can tell there isn't anything else related to what I am trying to achieve. When binding to a command the view updates when using an event handler in the code behind the view doesn't update. To me that makes no sense at all as my bindings and notification properties obviously work; just not from the code behind.

Comment: @chris okay well if this make sense to you then best of luck to you

Comment: @AnthonyRussell that's just it. This doesn't make sense. I don't why, using the same set of code, would the view update when using ICommand and not update when I don't use ICommand. I don't know what the difference is and I don't know what other code to show you. I'm not trying to be difficult, I simple don't understand.

Comment: What is your datacontext and where is it set? What and where is "CellEditorBinding"? Where is the code for "ObservableObject"? Where is  INotifyPropertyChanged implemented? Where does "UpdateCategoryData" live? Is it in your datacontext? Where is "TransactionEditCommand"? What does "TransactionEditCommand" and "CellEditorBinding" do? If you were asking "How do I set a color of the font?" Then you can post a few lines of code. When you are talking about three layers of architecture we need more than this to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I have added all the code that you mentioned. Thank you in advance for any help that you can offer. I hope I did not miss anything.

Comment: @chris I am going to review the code. Give me a day or so. In the mean time please look at this complete MVVM example and make sure you have all the required pieces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643782/how-to-bind-a-datagrid-row-with-text-boxes-in-wpf-mvvm/30762884#30762884

Comment: @Chris also, when you run and when you edit a cell what does your output window say? Any expression errors?

Comment: Everywhere you have a binding that is an input, if it's not read only then you should also include Mode=TwoWay otherwise the UI wont update the data model

Comment: Instead of using an event trigger for selection changed, why not just bind the selected item to a property in your view model? If you can avoid using UI to data events I would until you know proper MVVM architecture.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Thank you so much for all your help. The output window isn't showing any errors. I tried to use Mode=TwoWay; it didn't seem to do anything except give Error: 40 BindingExpression. I will review the link you gave me however. Thank you again.

Comment: @Chris, what does it say after Binding Expression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80439/discussion-between-chris-and-anthony-russell).